# Android media buttons not working while activity is not visible

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I'm having trouble getting the external media buttons to work in my app while the activity is not visible.

The media buttons work correctly while the activity is visible. I can play and pause the player without any issues by pressing the media buttons (while the activity is visible).

As soon as I minimize the activity (by pressing the Home button), the app stops responding to the media buttons.

I know this question has been asked a couple of times but it seems that I'm missing something that the other questions don't cover.

Here's a minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/HectorRicardo/android-media-buttons-not-working-mre/commit/a4ea01bf29ba7289e055767c5c935e35b7fbbcff

(the left side of the diff is basically a blank project from scratch created in Android Studio, while the right contains the minimal reproducible example)

What I have done so far:

- I've made sure that the `PlaybackState` always contains the `ACTION_PLAY`, `ACTION_PAUSE`, and `ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE` actions, for example:

```java
mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackStateBuilder
        .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1)
        .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
        .build())
```

- I've added a `MediaButtonReceiver` to my manifest:

```xml
<receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

- I've updated the `onStartCommand` of my `MediaBrowserService`:

```java
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSession, intent);
  return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

- I've made sure that the media session is active. Inside the `onPlay` method of the `MediaSessionCompat.Callback`, I do: `mediaSession.setActive()`.
- The `FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS` flag seems to be deprecated according to the [reference docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat#FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS). I tried adding it anyways, but it didn't help.

Not sure what else to check for. What am I missing?

Comment: So where are you calling `setFlags()` to say that you support media buttons and transport controls as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#init-session)?

Comment: Forgot to mention it in the question description ...those flags are deprecated according to the [reference docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat#FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS) .. I added those flags anyways to see if it worked, but it didn't

Comment: I updated the question to also mention this. thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? I think I'm experiencing the same problem.